# How is injectivity enough to show function is an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have some problem understanding one part of the proof of Cayley's theorem.

The theorem states that if $G$ is a group, then $G$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations. The first part of the proof is to use an earlier theorem stating that there exists a homomorphism $\phi :G\rightarrow S_G$ where $(\phi(a))(x)=ax$, $x\in G$. Then they show that $ker(\phi)=\{e\}$, which implies that the functions is injective. This is the end of the proof.

How does this show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism? Don't we need to show that it is surjective as well, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: The image of $\phi$ is a group of permutations, but generally not equal to $S_G$. For example, if $|G|=3$, what is $|S_G|$?

Comment: The phrase "group of permutations" means roughly "subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n\le\infty$", not "$S_n$".

Comment: @rogerl Or a subgroup of $S_X$ for some (possibly infinite) set $X$. There is no need to limit oneself to finite groups.

Comment: @5xum Hence "$n\le\infty$" in my comment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you show that $\phi$ is injective, there are two more steps which are hidden:

1. Show (or recall) that $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $S_G$.
2. Show that $\phi: G\to\phi(G)$ is an isomorphism.

Note that $\phi: G\to S_G$ is **not** an isomorphism, but $\phi: G\to\phi(G)$ **is** an isomorphism. While this may seem strange at first, remember that a function is defined not only by its action, but also by its **codomain** and **domain**. The two functions above differ in their codomains, and have different properties because of that.